# problems with NA in my dataframe

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R and I have some problem trying to find the correct code.

I have a dataframe "x" with 55 columns, but there are some NAs in some columns. 
I want to use apply() to count the number of cases in which there are a numeric object, but that function is counting also the NAs.

My question is if there is some way to modify my dataframe so I can 
use > apply(x, 2, length) without counting also the NAs

Please, help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `colSums`

```
colSums(!is.na(x))
#V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 
#18 16 18 16 17
```

Or

```
lengths(lapply(x, na.omit))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 20*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5))
```